# EF Code first Multi level inheritence issues

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a multi level inheriance heriarchy consisting of the following classes:

```
public abstract class BasePoco
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}


public class Activity : BasePoco
{
    public ActivityType ActivityType { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(1000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now there is a special type of Activity which is called a data capture activity.
Which is of two types: DataCaptureActivity and MasterDataCaptureActivity

```
public class DataCaptureActivityBase : Activity
{

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Derived Classes :

```
[Table("DataCaptureActivities")]
public class DataCaptureActivity : DataCaptureActivityBase
{
    public virtual DataCaptureActivityType DataCaptureActivityType { get; set; }
}

[Table("MasterDataCaptureActivities")]
public class MasterDataCaptureActivity : DataCaptureActivityBase
{
    public virtual string SomeOtherField{ get; set; }
}
```

The problem is upon creating a migration, The column `Title` which should be a part of `DataCaptureActivity` is actually coming up as a part of the `Activity` table.
Please note that `DataCaptureActivityBase` should not be a table in my schema. It is just for holding the common parameters `DataCaptureActivities` table and its inherited types.

The Schema I am targeting is :

```
Activity
-------------------------------
Id  | ActivityType  | Description

DataCaptureActivity
--------------------------------
Id | Title

MasterDataCaptureActivity
--------------------------------
Id | Title | SomeOtherField
```

Comment: Which levels of the inheritance hierarchy are you mapping to the database (by including DbSet properties for them in your DbContext)?  Sometimes it makes sense to only map the lowest levels in the database.

Comment: As David said the DbContext is very important here. If you are exposing DbSet<DataCaptureActivityBase> Title must be on DataCaptureActivityBase.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, @bubi Please see expected Schema, 
The problem is `Title` is being added to `Activity` table instead of the two derived tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your context is similar to this

```
public DbSet<Activity> Activity { get; set; } 
public DbSet<DataCaptureActivity> DataCaptureActivities { get; set; }
public DbSet<MasterDataCaptureActivity> MasterDataCaptureActivities { get; set; }
```

What you are conceptually saying to EF is that `DataCaptureActivity` is an `Activity` and that `MasterDataCaptureActivity` is an `Activity`. On the database you are creating all the three entities.
With this model, the statement

```
context.Activities.ToList();
```

retrieve all the `Activities` (the union of the three sets).

To do it with your model, EF on the database will create the Activity table with a Discriminator. The table structures will be this (look at 1-1 relationships):

```
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [Activity] (
 [Id] int not null identity(1,1)
, [ActivityType] int not null
, [Description] text null
, [Title] varchar(100) null
, [Discriminator] varchar(128) not null
);
ALTER TABLE [Activity] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Activity_7ea65be8] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [DataCaptureActivities] (
 [Id] int not null
, [DataCaptureActivityType] int not null
);
ALTER TABLE [DataCaptureActivities] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_DataCaptureActivities_7ea65be8] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [MasterDataCaptureActivities] (
 [Id] int not null
, [SomeOtherField] text null
);
ALTER TABLE [MasterDataCaptureActivities] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_MasterDataCaptureActivities_7ea65be8] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE INDEX [IX_Id] ON [DataCaptureActivities] ([Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE INDEX [IX_Id] ON [MasterDataCaptureActivities] ([Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
ALTER TABLE [DataCaptureActivities] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_DataCaptureActivities_Activity_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [Activity] ([Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
ALTER TABLE [MasterDataCaptureActivities] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_MasterDataCaptureActivities_Activity_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [Activity] ([Id])
```

Also, this statement

```
using (var context = new Context(GetConnection()))
{
    context.DataCaptureActivities.Add(new DataCaptureActivity() {Description = "Description"});
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Will generate this DML statements (2 insert statements!!!)

```
ExecuteDbDataReader==========
insert into [Activity]([ActivityType], [Description], [Title], [Discriminator])
values (@p0, @p1, null, @p2);
select [Id]
from [Activity]
where [Id] = @@identity
@p0 = 0
@p1 = Description
@p2 = DataCaptureActivity
ExecuteNonQuery==========
insert into [DataCaptureActivities]([Id], [DataCaptureActivityType])
values (@p0, @p1);

@p0 = 1
@p1 = 0
```

**The solution to target your tables**

You need to change your model saying that DataCaptureActivities and MasterDataCaptureActivities are not Activities.

For example:

```
public abstract class BasePoco
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}


public class BaseActivity : BasePoco
{
    public ActivityType ActivityType { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(1000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

[Table("Activity")]
public class Activity : BaseActivity
{
}

public class DataCaptureActivityBase : BaseActivity
{

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

[Table("DataCaptureActivities")]
public class DataCaptureActivity : DataCaptureActivityBase
{
    public virtual DataCaptureActivityType DataCaptureActivityType { get; set; }
}

[Table("MasterDataCaptureActivities")]
public class MasterDataCaptureActivity : DataCaptureActivityBase
{
    public virtual string SomeOtherField { get; set; }
}
```

In this case, the tables structures will be this

```
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [Activity] (
 [Id] int not null identity(1,1)
, [ActivityType] int not null
, [Description] text null
);
ALTER TABLE [Activity] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Activity_2b28bd47] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [DataCaptureActivities] (
 [Id] int not null identity(1,1)
, [DataCaptureActivityType] int not null
, [Title] varchar(100) null
, [ActivityType] int not null
, [Description] text null
);
ALTER TABLE [DataCaptureActivities] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_DataCaptureActivities_2b28bd47] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [MasterDataCaptureActivities] (
 [Id] int not null identity(1,1)
, [SomeOtherField] text null
, [Title] varchar(100) null
, [ActivityType] int not null
, [Description] text null
);
ALTER TABLE [MasterDataCaptureActivities] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_MasterDataCaptureActivities_2b28bd47] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
```

But in this case, if you want to enum all the `ActivityBase` you need to join them (`Union`) on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the below steps.

- Mark Activity class with a Table Attribute
- Mark DataCaptureActivityBase as `abstract`
- In OnModelCreating Map Derived Entities with `MapInheritedProperties();`

Hope this helps